# how to filter a words in list that don't Repeat in python?

Tags: python, list

I want to remove duplicate items from a list and keep the order of the original list, as in the example I have:

```
['hangman', 'song', 'most', 'broadly', 'song', 'hangman', 'work', 'music', 'work', 'broadly', 'typically']
```

and I want this:

```
['hangman', 'song', 'most', 'broadly', 'work', 'music', 'typically']
```

How can I do this :

Comment: Please review this, on how to create a minimal complete verifiable example, and maybe actually attempt to do this homework before asking the user-base here to do it for you? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Also review this page for guidance on how to ask homework questions here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: have you tried `set(your_list)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set` for this, set will not accept one item more than once:

```
old_list = ['hangman', 'song', 'most', 'broadly', 'song', 'hangman', 'work', 'music', 'work', 'broadly', 'typically'] 

new_list = list(set(old_list))
```

The `new_list` will be:

```
['hangman', 'song', 'most', 'broadly', 'work', 'music', 'typically']
```

Answer (score 1):

this will keep the order of your old_list in case you need to.

```
old_list = ['hangman', 'song', 'most', 'broadly', 'song', 'hangman', 'work', 'music', 'work', 'broadly', 'typically']

new_list = []

for n in old_list:
    if n not in new_list:
        new_list.append(n)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)). Python set implementation docs here (assuming you are using python3)[enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). Using the first list as an input you can add all elements to the set and the add operation will ignore duplicates. However when reading back from the set the order is not guaranteed.

example:

```
>>> mylist = ["a", "b", "c", "a"]
>>> myset = set(mylist)
>>> myset
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates and keep the order of the original list in Python 3.7 you can use `dict.fromkeys()`:

```
l = ['hangman', 'song', 'most', 'broadly', 'song', 'hangman', 'work', 'music', 'work', 'broadly', 'typically'] 

list(dict.fromkeys(l))
# ['hangman', 'song', 'most', 'broadly', 'work', 'music', 'typically']
```

Otherwise use `OrderedDict`.